# How do i run a function when user leave page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to delete a data from firebase if the user leaves page, so i need a function that detect user from leaving page, i do some search on the internet but none of them work, but i doubt this is my mistakes too

this is my code

```
window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;

function closingCode() {
  let whdb = db
    .collection("chats")
    .doc("room1")
    .collection("users")
    .doc(userSession);

  whdb.delete();

  return null;
}
```

any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event that allows you to run code before the user exits the page and also allows you to prompt them for if they want to exit. However, asynchronous code such as making a web request to your server is not guaranteed to work.